# Sink AVRO messages from pulsar topic to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-pulsar, sink

It is possible to sink messages from pulsar topic which uses avro schema? Im try to use this solution:

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/next/io-elasticsearch-sink/

But my problem is if i want to use the connector with the option "schemaEnable : true" then i get the follow error

```
Uncaught exception in Java Instance
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: **Unknown AVRO schema type=ENUM**
        at org.apache.pulsar.io.elasticsearch.JsonConverter.toJson(JsonConverter.java:105) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.pulsar.io.elasticsearch.JsonConverter.toJson(JsonConverter.java:51) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.pulsar.io.elasticsearch.JsonConverter.toJson(JsonConverter.java:97) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.pulsar.io.elasticsearch.JsonConverter.toJson(JsonConverter.java:51) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.pulsar.io.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchSink.extractJsonNode(ElasticSearchSink.java:285) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.pulsar.io.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchSink.stringifyValue(ElasticSearchSink.java:261) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.pulsar.io.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchSink.extractIdAndDocument(ElasticSearchSink.java:177) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.pulsar.io.elasticsearch.ElasticSearchSink.write(ElasticSearchSink.java:84) ~[?:?]
        at
```

Do we need a custom sink connector in this case?

Thank you very much!